# Is paypal credit card payment secure?

Tags: php, paypal

I am developing an application which is using paypal credit card payment.
I got a php example from paypal's developer page. This example is directly accepting users credit card details using normal html form. I wonder how the security is managed in this kind of payment system. What I believe is, if we get a user's credit card details, we will be able to make payments in future without the permission of the user.

I think I might miss some points about paypal credit card payment. Please guide me with correct informations.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The data that is being sent to paypal needs to be encrypted Point to Point with HTTPS at the very least. Furthermore, never EVER store user's credit card details on your server, in case you were event thinking about that. If you have `reoccuring` payments, that's a whole different topic

Comment: Could you point us to the link of the source code you were using?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you won't copy the inputs in the form, the payment is secure. Using a HTML form means that the credit card information is passed to paypal via HTTP via the forms method and action.

If you ensure that the forms method is "POST" and the actions protocol is "HTTPS", the users browser will do the SSL handshake and encryption stuff.

NEVER EVER use method "GET" with sensitive data.

```
<form method="POST" action="https://something.paypal.com/">
<input type="text" name="owner">
<input type="text" name="creditcardno">
<input type="text" name="expirationdate">
<input type="password" name="checksum">
</form>
```

Please keep in mind that this is just a code example. It won't work that way. Just want to show how such a form should look like.

Answer (score 1):

Its fully secured.

Because, You send url to paypal gateway and do payment process, all the url data will be encrypted.

Comment: No, it is not "fully" secured (see answer below).

Answer (score 1):

It is as secure as paypal made it to be.

Paypal gives you acces to their API. This means you have to follow precise rules Paypal creates for you. Not doing so will result in a failure in requests.

I even think they redirect you to paypal.com so the actual payment isn't done on your server. The only thing you will have to do is listen to paypal if they received the payment and process the order on your side.

Comment: > I even think they redirect you to paypal.com 
> so the actual payment isn't done on your server. 
Both is possible. It depends on the API. When using REST in the US or US with a qualifying account, the buyer actually does not leave your website.

Comment: Never made it myself. But when I'm purchasing goods online I usually get redirected to paypal. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

> I got a php example from paypal's developer page. This example is directly accepting users credit 
>   card details using normal html form. I wonder how the security is managed in this kind of payment
>   system.

Generally speaking, not at all. You are expected to send the form over https, but even so, it does not make it safe as the data can be intercepted. This is why Stripe and Brain Tree use JavaScript libraries to encrypt the form before submission (and even this is not completely safe if your web page happens to give access to the form to some malicious JS, for example through 3rd party ads; these scripts could also intercept cleartext data before it is encrypted and submitted).

I assume you are sending this form to your own server. If this is the case, then obtaining PCI compliance will be all that more difficult because you will have to prove that your server is hacker-proof. With Brain Tree Transparent Redirect and Stripe Checkout, credit card information never even passes your server, simplifying PCI compliance.

Stripe is particularly interesting. Stripe encrypts payment details using JavaScript and submits the form to itself (by using Stripe.js on unnamed form fields that cannot be POSTed). The Stripe server then injects a token into your original form. As a result, your script can only POST the token along with other customer details to your server, not the payment details.

> What I believe is, if we get a user's credit card details, we will be able to make payments 
>   in future without the permission of the user.

This is not how it works.

Capturing credit card details to charge the user in violation of PayPal terms could get you into some big trouble. You have to use appropriate APIs and these do not give you access to credit card details. This is the core idea of PayPal being PayPal.

For Example, with Authorize & Capture, you have 28 days sharp to capture the payment and you can request a new authorization only one single time during this period. This is not meant for recurring payments.

You can set up subscriptions using REST APIs or even ExpressCheckOut, but capturing credit card information of the user to charge them without their knowledge could get your PayPal account closed or worse. Use the appropriate APIs that PayPal tells you to for you use case and all will be fine.

For recurring payments, Brain Tree offers to capture buyer's credit card information in its secure vault, giving you the ability to charge the card repeatedly without having to worry about security of the information.

> I am developing an application which is using paypal credit card payment.

Why don't you use Brain Tree (it's been part of PayPal since the acquisition at the end of 2013). It could make your life a lot easier.